# Insert a dynamically created struct item into a vector of structs

Tags: c++

I'm trying to fill a vector of structs with dynamically created struct elements.
All of the code below is contained into a class named TD_Dijkstra_OS

Struct:

```
struct instFunDescLeg
 {
float Ap, Bp, tfail;
typename GraphType::NodeIterator n; //external library data type 
};
```

I compute the values needed to assign in the item's fiels into a function as:

```
           v = G.target( e);

            FunDataType Ap, Bp, offset, slope;

    v->dist = getEarliestArrivalTime( e, u->dist, slope, offset); //TEST
            //if( getEarliestArrivalTime( e, u->dist, slope, offset) != v->dist)
            //    continue;

            Ap = ( 1 + slope) * u->Ap;
            Bp = ( 1 + slope) * u->Bp + offset;

            if( v->timestamp != (*m_timestamp))
            {
                v->Ap = Ap;
                v->Bp = Bp;

                Q.push( v);
                v->timestamp = (*m_timestamp);
            }

            else
            {
                if( Ap < v->Ap)
                {
                    v->Ap = Ap;
                    v->Bp = Bp;
                }

                else if( Ap == v->Ap && Bp > v->Bp)
                    v->Bp = Bp;
            }
            v->tfail = v->dist;
            storeInstFunDescLeg(v);
```

and then i create a struct item and try to insert it to a vector of instFunDescLeg items, declared as:

```
  std::vector<struct instFunDescLeg> bp;
```

into this function:

```
 void storeInstFunDescLeg(const NodeIterator& u)
{
//representation: (idn:(Ap(tfail),Bp(tfail),idfn(tfail))), for a node identified by idn
//store into a vector
instFunDescLeg* leg;
leg = new instFunDescLeg();

leg->Ap = u->Ap;
leg->Bp = u->Bp;
leg->tfail = u->tfail;
leg->n = u;

bp.push_back(leg);
}
```

When I compile this, I get an error message which says that there's no function matching bp.push_back(leg). A note after the error message sheds some light to this situation:

```
 /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:826:7: σημείωση:   no known conversion for 
 argument 1 from ‘TD_Dijkstra_OS<DynamicGraph<AdjacencyListImpl, node, edge>
```

> ::instFunDescLeg*’ to ‘const value_type& {aka const 
>   TD_Dijkstra_OS >::instFunDescLeg&}’

Can someone help me with the implementation of the insert procedure?

Comment: Hint: you are attempting to insert a pointer into a vector that holds objects.

Comment: Remove the `new` line and it should work fine. There are extra `struct`s in there as well.

Comment: May I keep the instFunDescLeg* leg; or should I change this to instFunDescLeg leg;

Comment: Use the latter. Pointers are generally inferior if you can help it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector<struct instFunDescLeg> bp;` should be written `std::vector<instFunDescLeg> bp;`

Your struct is fairly simple, so I see no need to store a vector of pointers to it with what you are provided.  If there is some hidden requirement that would force you to use pointers, try to hide them behind smart pointer classes (e.g. `unique_ptr`).